# behavior of float in css

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web

Here is a css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Jenware | Personalized Gifts</title>
<style type="text/css">


/* styles for navigation */
#nav {
    background-color: #2322ff;
    height: 3em;
    width:70em;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 auto;     

} 
#nav ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    float:left;
}

 #nav ul li a {     
  display: block;   
  padding: .5em;    
  border: 1px solid #ba89a8; 
  border-radius: .5em;  
  margin: .25em; 

}    
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="">House</a></li>
<li><a href="">Baby</a></li>
<li><a href="">More</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- end #content -->
</body>
</html>
```

It appears as follows
[image]

where as if the css is following

```
}
#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 auto;     
    float:left;
}
```

then following appears
[image]
I am unable to understand the behavior of `float:left` in above images.
Why in 2nd kind of css it is getting down one by one? where as in first one it is coming properly?

Comment: I don't see that problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Hrgj5/

Comment: well you have not understood the question I feel, why are the individual li elements going down in 2nd css, but not in first one

Comment: I don't see them going down either by following your code above. [jsfiddle.net/5U92u/](http://jsfiddle.net/5U92u/) Go to that fiddle and see what's missing to recreate the problem, (because I couldn't recreate the problem from just the above info.).  You might want to do this because other people probably can't recreate your problem either.  I'm assuming that you removed your float left from the li items and if you did it that makes sense why they are on seperate lines, because block level elements don't stay on the same line naturally and list items are block level elements.

Comment: What browser are you testing with @Registered User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the problem with the second code. When you `float:left;` in the first case, you apply it to the `<li>` elements, so each `<li>` is floated to the left.

In the second case, you apply `float:left;` to the `<ul>` element. CSS does it's job correctly and **floats the container to the left** leaving the `<li>` elements inside unchanged. So they stack on top of each other like they normally do, because you haven't told them to do otherwise.

The reason drip and John didn't see the problem is that you didn't tell us that in the second case, you also remove `float:left;` from the `<li>` styles. In the future, it's super helpful if you create a jsFiddle like they did to show exactly the code you are using. Let me know if you need more explanation, I'll be happy to try and clarify it.

Comment: I got it more over `margin:0 auto` is something which puts the elements of containing element to center if width is given I was not aware of this fact also, I came to know this later

Answer (score 0):

The `margin:0 auto` and `float:left` seem to conflict. To center the nav, place `margin:0 auto` on `#nav`.

edit: forgot to mention to clear after the float.

edit: maybe i should've inquired why you'd want to float the ul in the first place.

Comment: no that did not worked I did `#nav {
 background-color: #2322ff;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 height: 3em;
 width:100em;
}
#nav ul {
 list-style:none; 
}` but it did not gave me desired experience, the effect was some thing similar to image 2 in question just with width equal to entire screen in individual li elements

Answer (score 0):

The normal behaviour of float is to resize the container size as per content/child length. In first scenario LI are coming in single line because the parent is able to provide them complete width.
But in the case of second one, UL gets resize as per its child witch has max width. And, hence they are appearing underneath each other.

Comment: I am not fully able to understand what you said can you provide any web link for the same

Comment: To understand more, please add float attribute to div to see visual change: 
    #nav {
     background-color: #2322ff;
     height: 3em;
     width: 70em;
     float: left;
    }